# The screen in Android Virtual Device is too big

Tags: android

As you can see in the screenshot, what appears is only a small one in the upper left corner, but the frame is very large. The operation also follows the size of the frame, so if I want to press the gallery I have to go to the bottom of the frame and press with guesswork. Can anyone help me? I'm a newbie to Android Studio and this was quite annoying for my first try.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8tMn.jpg

Comment: Btw, the version of Android Studio I'm using is version 3.6 running on Windows with AMD Mobile processor

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your emulator screen

By going (in the top menu of Android Studio) to Run > Edit Configurations

In the left panel of the just opened dialog, choose your application.

In the right panel, choose the General tab, and then go down and check Emulator, and in Prefer Android Virtual Device, choose the virtual device you are currently using.

Now, go the tab Emulator (next to the General tab), and in Additional command line options, write

-scale 0.X

where X can be for example 25 or 50, which would represent respectively 25% and 50% of original size.